# Rotate android sensor axis with respect to a vehicle frame

Tags: rotation, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm struggling lately with a reorientation problem.
Let say we have put android device inside a vehicle frame. 
We can calculate the rotation matrix of with respect to world coordinates but can we reorient android with respect to the vehicle frame?
For examle i calculate the Rotation Matrix and apply that to my accelerometer readings and than try to see how does it compare with the signal from another device aligned with vehicle frame.
The point is i cannot get it. Can smone hint smth on how to achieve a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand, but:

If you want the devices position relative to the frame, you need some way of determining the difference. When it is installed, you could save that orientation and compare movements from that reference? Or, as you said, a second sensor could be used to detect the orientation differ between them, but again zero will need to be calibrated from the installation location.

If you can clarify what data you're trying to obtain, I can clarify my answer.

Comment: Consider we have a frame accelerating horizonatally and the accelerometer placed inside the frame randomly. We can calculate the vertical axis (Z) but not the heading of the frame because of the Yaw. But if the frame is accelerating vertically will that acceleration show up in the other axis. so we can rotate them to align with the heading of the frame?